# JS Time elapsed since a date

Tags: javascript, date

I'd like to calculate the elapsed time between two dates. I saw some examples on the internet (most of them on this site), but found nothing useful. I'd like to write a function  can call like this:

```
calculateDifference('2012-02-01 15:31')
```

There is no second parameter, since it is the current date. I have a code I'm currently using, which is:

```
    function get_time_diff(_datetime )
    {
      var datetime = new Date( _datetime ).getTime();
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      if( isNaN(datetime) )
      {
        return " on " + _datetime;
      }


      if (datetime < now) {
        var milisec_diff = now - datetime;
      }else{
        var milisec_diff = datetime - now;
      }

      var days = Math.floor(milisec_diff / 1000 / 60 / (60 * 24));

      var date_diff = new Date( milisec_diff );
      var respvalue ='';

      if (days > 0) {
        respvalue += days + " day(s), ";
      }

      if (date_diff.getHours() > 0) {
        respvalue += (date_diff.getHours() - 1) + " hour(s) and ";
      }

      respvalue += date_diff.getMinutes() + " minute(s) ago.";
      return respvalue;
    }
```

And the result is and should be:

```
1 day(s), 14 hour(s) and 17 minute(s)
```

For some reasons there are differences (when 1 day passed it shows 0 etc) and it works only with chrome, in IE and FF it returns with the date I passed as the parameter. 
Once again: I'd like to calculate the difference between the current date and a given date in the next format:

```
1 day(s), 14 hour(s) and 17 minute(s)
```

I don't care about the months, years. Only hours, mins and secs. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  function get_time_diff(_datetime )
  {
    var datetime = new Date( _datetime ).getTime();
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    if( isNaN(datetime) )
    {
      return " on " + _datetime;
    }


    if (datetime < now) {
      var milisec_diff = now - datetime;
    }else{
      var milisec_diff = datetime - now;
    }

    var days = Math.floor(milisec_diff / 1000 / 60 / (60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor(milisec_diff / (1000 * 60 * 60) - days * 24);
    var minutes = Math.floor(milisec_diff / (1000 * 60) - days * 24 * 60 - hours * (60));

    var respvalue ='';

    if (days > 0) {
      respvalue += days + " day(s), ";
    }

    if (hours > 0) {
      respvalue += hours + " hour(s) and ";
    }

    respvalue += minutes + " minute(s) ago.";

    return respvalue;
  }
```

Comment: Works better than the original, finally there are no deifferences. However, unfortunately it does not work with IE and FF :( Do you have any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your date format is not valid, so Firefox can't parse your strings as dates.

You can use

```
function get_time_diff(datetime) {
      var milisec_diff = Math.abs(new Date() - new Date(datetime)),
          diff = new Date(milisec_diff),
          days = milisec_diff / 3600e3 / 24 | 0,
          hours = diff.getUTCHours(),
          respvalue = '';
      if (days)
          respvalue += days + " day(s), ";
      if (hours)
          respvalue += hours + " hour(s) and ";
      respvalue += diff.getUTCMinutes() + " minute(s) ago.";
      return respvalue;
}
get_time_diff('2012-02-01T15:31Z');
```

Where the date `2012-02-01T15:31Z` is in [ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), and the `Z` means UTC time (note some browsers may not support it).

Comment: If you don't have the "Z" at the end, Safari 5 doesn't support it, other than than all modern browsers will support that.   Also, make sure you *always* have a Z to make the calculation consistent across browsers.   The ISO spec indicates that if you don't have the Z, then the time should be interpreted as local time, which is what IE and Firefox do, but Chrome and Opera assume the ISO time is in UTC regardless if Z is there or not.   So if you know your UTC time isn't specifying a time-zone, my suggestion is to add the Z at the end if it's not there.

Comment: I have the time in the following format: 2000-01-01 01:01 
Tried your code, works fine with chrome, but in FF it returns: NaN minute(s). Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: @KissKoppány Your format is not valid, you can use `2000-01-01T01:01` (local) or `2000-01-01T01:01Z` (UTC). See [ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15).

Comment: Got the same output: NaN minute(s) when used the way like 2011-01-01 15:00:00Z

Comment: By the way. I don't know how should I do this. This function would be for a site to show the users, how much time has passed since a comment. And I can't make sure, they're in the same timezone. What would you recommend me?

Comment: @KissKoppány If you compare dates from users around the world, use UTC dates instead of local ones.

Comment: In that case the user would see he has commented 6 hours ago (for example) when he commented right in that moment (depending on the timezone), wouldn't he?

Comment: @KissKoppány No, because `new Date().getTime()` doesn't depend on timezone.

Comment: Cool :) How could I convert my date format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS) to UTC format?

Comment: Got it, var datetime = new Date(_datetime).toISOString();

Comment: Works with chrome (improperly) but not with other browsers.

Comment: @KissKoppány Better avoid custom date formats, it's a mess, and since ISO8601 isn't widely supported, better use RFC 2822. When an user posts a comment, save the date using `dateStr = date.toUTCString()`. To calculate the difference, use `new Date() - new Date(dateStr)`. But to avoid being fooled, better save the date server-side.

Answer (score 1):

This seems simplest to me:

http://jsbin.com/tusul/9/edit

```
// end date is optional, it will assume the current date if not supplied.
// if timezone is not supplied, it will assume local browser time.
function calculateDateDiff(beginDate, endDate) {
  var currentDate;
  if (typeof(endDate) == 'undefined') {
    currentDate = new Date();
  } else {
    currentDate = new Date(endDate);
  }
  var targetDate = new Date(beginDate);

  var differenceDate;
  if (currentDate > targetDate) {
    differenceDate = new Date(currentDate - targetDate); 
  } else {
    differenceDate = new Date(targetDate - currentDate);
  }

  return('Days: ' + (differenceDate.getUTCDate() -1) + ', Hours: ' + differenceDate.getUTCHours() + ', Minutes: ' + differenceDate.getUTCMinutes() + ', Seconds: ' + differenceDate.getUTCSeconds());
}

console.log(calculateDateDiff('05-22-2014 01:02:03', '05-22-2014 02:03:04'));
console.log(calculateDateDiff('05-22-2014 01:02:03', '05-22-2014 02:03:04-600'));
console.log(calculateDateDiff('05-22-2014 01:02:03Z', '05-22-2014 02:03:04Z'));
console.log(calculateDateDiff('05-22-2014 01:02:03Z', '05-22-2014 02:03:04-600'));
console.log(calculateDateDiff('05-22-2014 01:02:03-500', '05-22-2014 02:03:04-600'));
console.log(calculateDateDiff('05-22-2014 01:02:03+1000', '05-22-2014 02:03:04-600'));
```

Comment: My answer assumes when you say "I don't care about the months, years" you will be dropping them (or not comparing dates with that difference).  If you want to convert them into days (e.g. 65 days, 3 hours, 2 minutes...) this would need to be altered slightly.